# How to give a permission to create marketing api user in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

How do I give permission to create marketing API user in Marketing Cloud? I am not able to create users.

Answer (score 0):

**Knowledge Article**

[Marketing Cloud Connector: Create Marketing Cloud API User](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000263757&language=en_US&type=1)

> 1. In the Marketing Cloud, navigate to Email Studio.
> 2. Click Admin.
> 3. Click My Users.
> 4. Click Create.
> 5. Name the user so it can be easily identified (example: api-user-1234).
> 6. Enter your email address as the Reply Email and Notification Email Addresses.
> 7. Enter a unique username.
> 8. Leave the External ID field blank (unless required by your organization).
> 9. Set a Time Zone.
> 10. Set a Culture Code.
> 11. Select API User.
> 12. Create a temporary Password.
> 13. If you are using a non-enterprise 2.0 account, set the following roles and permissions on this page:   User Permissions: NONE Marketing
>       Cloud Permissions and Roles: NONE Select Email Application Select
>       Mobile Connect (if applicable) Select Marketing Cloud Administrator
>       role
> 14. Click Save.

**Additional instructions for Enterprise 2.0 accounts Continue to set
roles and permissions:**

> 1. Click My Users from Email Studio Admin.
> 2. Select the Marketing Cloud API User.
> 3. Click Manage Roles.
> 4. Click Edit Roles.
> 5. Assign the following roles:   Administrator Marketing Cloud Administrator
> 6. Click Save.

Comment: I have Already use this steps as you mention but create button is not visible

Comment: Click My Users from Email Studio Admin.
Select the Marketing Cloud API User.
Click Manage Roles.------> this is disable .

Comment: Click My Users from Email Studio Admin
Select the Marketing Cloud API User.